# AzureDevops: How to manage test activity with task on Kanban task board sprint

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am wondering if there is a way of using test cases, test suites or possibly even test plans with task workitems on the Kanban sprint board. Similar as can be done with bugs ("Bugs are managed with requirements").

Currently when creating a parent relation for any task to an existing test case, test suite or test plan, the workitem task remains unparented on the board. I would like to see the parent relation as a requirement to have a better insight and planning method for test-user's activities on the sprint board of VSO.

[Example of task workitem on sprint board related to test suite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNiWY.png)

So my question is: how can I make the task-parent relation visible on the sprint taskboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not supported on boards to link and view test plans/suite. I think, you can try one of:

1. Create an user story as place-holder and link it to a test plan/suite.
2. Use out-of-box way to work with tests: [Add, run, and update inline tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/add-run-update-tests?view=azure-devops)
3. Create a custom work item query to view your work structure: [Create and save managed queries with the query editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I've used your first solution. Added an extra user-story related to the development feature, which functions as a placeholder for managing test activities such as creating and executing test cases.This is indeed a workable method, although would be nice when tasks on the task board can be directly linked to test plan/suite in the near future.